# Hide Accesibility icon from Panel

Tags: icons, 18.04, panel, gnome-shell

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and set the Scaling Factor in Tweaks to 1,10 because the 1920x1080 resolution makes stuff on my screen look a bit too small for my taste. That toggled this stickman icon, which now seems to not want to go away from my Panel unless I disable "Large Text".

[image: Accesibility icon]

Is there any way to hide this icon while keeping my settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Icon Hider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/). It provides you the granular control over the the top bar icons, lets you hide/show indicators individually.

Once installed, toggle off the "**a11y**" item in the extension's *preferences* window.

[image]

You may have to re-login to see the change.